# How do I select a top-level attribute of an XML column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery-sql

I have an XML column in SQL Server that is the equivalent of:

```
<Test foo="bar">
  <Otherstuff baz="belch" />
</Test>
```

I want to get the value of the `foo` attribute of Test (the root element) as a varchar. My goal would be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT CAST('<Test foo="bar"><Otherstuff baz="belch" /></Test>' AS xml).value('@foo', 'varchar(20)') AS Foo
```

But when I run the above query, I get the following error:

> Msg 2390, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> XQuery [value()]: Top-level attribute
> nodes are not supported

Answer (score 46, accepted):

John Saunders has it almost right :-)

```
declare @Data XML
set @Data = '<Test foo="bar"><Otherstuff baz="belch" /></Test>'

select @Data.value('(/Test/@foo)[1]','varchar(20)') as Foo
```

This works for me (SQL Server 2005 and 2008)

Marc

Comment: what if you don't know what the root element is..???  in this case we know it is "Test", but I have an XML field that has different XML depending on the value in another field.  so it could be <book> or <something_else>...  is there a default root element name we can use..???

Comment: @Ads use a wildcard, e.g. `//Element[@foo]` or if you know something about the structure `/*/Elements/Element[@foo]`

Comment: Wrap the query in parens.  Sheesh; I would've never guessed.  The XML querying in TSQL works great, but the syntax is way too difficult.

Answer (score 7):

If you dont know the root element:

```
select @Data.value('(/*/@foo)[1]','varchar(20)') as Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Why does `.value('@foo', 'varchar(20)')` generate the error “Top-level attribute nodes are not supported”?

When you query the `xml` data type, the context is the *document node*, which is an implicit node that contains the root element(s) of your XML document. The document node has no name and no attributes.

#### How can I get the value of an attribute on the root element?

In your XQuery expression, include the path to the first root element:

```
DECLARE @Data xml = '<Customer ID="123"><Order ID="ABC" /></Customer>'

SELECT @Data.value('Customer[1]/@ID', 'varchar(20)')
-- Result: 123
```

If you don’t know (or don’t want to specify) the name of the root element, then just use `*` to match any element:

```
SELECT @Data.value('*[1]/@ID', 'varchar(20)')
-- Result: 123
```

Because the query context is the document node, you don’t need to prefix the XQuery expression with a forward slash (as the other answers unnecessarily do).

#### Why do I have to include `[1]`?

The XQuery expression you pass to `value()` must be *guaranteed* to return a singleton. The expression `Customer/@ID` doesn’t satisfy this requirement because it matches both `ID="123"` and `ID="456"` in the following example:

```
DECLARE @Data xml = '<Customer ID="123" /><Customer ID="456" />'
```

Remember that the `xml` data type represents an XML document fragment, not an XML document, so it can contain multiple root elements.

#### What’s the difference between `Customer[1]/@ID` and `(Customer/@ID)[1]`?

The expression `Customer[1]/@ID` retrieves the `ID` attribute of the first `<Customer>` element.

The expression `(Customer/@ID)[1]` retrieves the `ID` attribute of all `<Customer>` elements, and from this list of attributes, picks the first.

The following example demonstrates the difference:

```
DECLARE @Data xml = '<Customer /><Customer ID="123" /><Customer ID="456" />'

SELECT @Data.value('Customer[1]/@ID', 'varchar(20)')
-- Result: NULL (because the first Customer element doesn't have an ID attribute)

SELECT @Data.value('(Customer/@ID)[1]', 'varchar(20)')
-- Result: 123
```